# Is there a Macro to use "λ" character as "lambda" in R5RS Scheme?

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp, r5rs, gambit

Is there a Macro to use "λ" character as "lambda" in R5RS Scheme? [From here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/61o_0K5Wzxs/KQqCIAYhjtwJ) In Gambit "scheme-r5rs" I tried:

```
(define-syntax λ
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ . more) (lambda . more))))
```

But I keep getting `Ill-formed expression` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a reader macro, but I don't think they are standardised in Scheme.

This works:

```
# pu@pumbair: ~  cat test2.scm
(define-syntax λ
    (syntax-rules ()
       ((_ param body ...) (lambda param body ...))))
(display ((λ (x y) (+ x y)) 1 2)) (newline)
(display ((λ () 1))) (newline)
(display ((λ (a . b) b) 'a 'b 'c)) (newline)

# pu@pumbair: ~  gsi -:s test2.scm
3
1
(b c)
```

Comment: Neither version worked with Gambit R5RS. I will try the mailing list.

Comment: @GlassGhost It does, in "standard" Scheme mode. See my update please.

Comment: Wow it works but only from the command line, not if the file is invoked  as #!/usr/bin/env scheme-r5rs how do set the -:s option from within the file?

Comment: @GlassGhost Use `#!/usr/bin/env scheme-r5rs -:s`.

Comment: I tried that, the linux #!/usr/bin/env doesn't pass command line options

Comment: @GlassGhost Works fine on OS X. Try without `env` then?

Comment: You've already done so much, I'm gonna mark it as accepted and sort this out in the mailing list.